# Sieve of Eratosthenes, array is too large that memory out of bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I want to get all prime numbers between 2 and pow(2, 32), but, since pow(2, 32) is to large that I can not declare that large array. The following are my codes

```
struct prims_n
{
    long long *prim;
    long long  size;
};

struct prims_n get_prim_number(long long number)
{
    long long count = 0;
    struct prims_n result;
    bool* a = new bool[number+1];
    memset(a, 1, number+1);
    for(long long i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i ++)
    {
        if(a[i])
        {
            for(long long j = 2; j <= number/i; j ++)
            {
                a[i*j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (long long i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]) count ++;
    }
    result.size = count;
    long long k = 0;
    result.prim = new long long[count];
    for (long long i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {

        if (a[i] && k < count)
        {
            result.prim[k] = i;
            k ++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    struct  prims_n result = get_prim_number(pow(2, 26));
    cout << "prim numbers:" << result.size 
        << " pow(2, 32)=" <<  pow(2, 32) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My OS is `Windows` and IDE is `Visual Studio 2012`.
The number pow(2, 32) is too large and the `Sieve of Eratosthenes` is not computational efficient. So, what should I do?

Comment: You could use BIGNUM type. It is avalaible for example in OpenSSL library. Thus you'll be able to perform operations on numbers of arbitrary size.

Comment: Compile for 64-bits? But of course, that will only take you so far, since it will run out of memory sooner or later...

Comment: You can also use one bit per number found, rather than a whole byte.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, yes, 64-bits

Comment: @Alexander Use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for that.

Comment: So, are you complaining that it takes a long time (that is expected - that's one of the reasons why prime numbers are "hard to calculate")

Comment: Is your task to implement "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm or is it to find primes using whatever algorithm you want?

Comment: @StillLearning, I have implement the `Sieve of Eratosthenes` when the number is not that large and I think there maybe better algorithm to get primes.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin - it should have much better performance

Comment: Hint: How often will a prime exceeding sqrt(maxWanted) be the smallest prime divisor of bigger numbers? `Sieve of Eratosthenes is not [computationally] efficient` - ? What is, by how much, and can you code it?

Comment: Do a search for "segmented" or "paged" sieve of Eratosthenes:  you'll find that there are implementations that only use a very small (optionally bit packed) sieve buffer plus storage for the base primes up to the square root of the sieving range (which base primes can also be encoded/compressed).  You'll also find that segmented sieves can be written to be unbounded so that they can grow as required up to much larger ranges limited by memory and processing speed (they are also faster).  In this way, one could process all the primes up to 10^16 in a month or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way: build for 64 bit target and install a lot of RAM.

Or you could reduce the needed memory by not storing an int for each number but a bit only. `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset<N>` would be good containers to use. `bitset` requires the size to be known at compile time, `vector` allows it to change. BTW, `vector<bool>` is specialized for optimized memory usage.

Of course you do not really need to store all numbers 1..N because you know that the even numbers cannot be prime numbers. So you could use an array where for example the element at index `i` represents the information if `2*i+1` is a prime number.

Other option: only store the prime numbers, then for each new number to test try to divide it by the prime numbers you already calculated and stored (not all, only up to sqrt()).

Or work with windowed views into the sieve: store the known prime numbers in one container and allocate space for part of the complete buffer. If you are done with the buffer, then move to the next window.

Comment: Here's an implementation of the "Other option" (only store primes): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86cace53cbf7b4b4 I think it should work nicely.

Comment: I suppose we could make that implementation twice as fast by starting at 5 and incrementing by 2 (since no even number will ever be prime).

Answer (score -2):

Prime numbers are on the form (6K + 1) or (6K - 1),
Loop over k and check if 6K+1 or 6K-1 is not divisible by 2,3,5,7 to be prime

Comment: That's not ALL prime numbers, right - at least not the rule of 2,3,5,7 - you need to check other numbers too.

Comment: It should be checked if a number is divisible by any prime up to its square root, but not only by 2, 3, 5, 7

Comment: and testing for 2 is probably not worth any the cpu cycles.

Comment: Testing for 3 isn't worth the CPU cycles either, as (6K+1)/3 has remainder 1. This answer fails to understand why these two forms are relevant.